# How do I enable %UserProfile% for scripting with Folder Redirection?

Tags: vbscript

I'm experimenting with Folder Redirection and after getting it set up, I quickly realized that any VBS scripts that have environmental variables such as %UserProfile% become unusable.

For example:

```
 C:\MD %UserProfile%\Desktop\Not_Created_On_Real_Desktop\
```

And

```
'Place to deposit excel output file
Depo=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%" & "\Desktop\Folder_This_User_Needs_Easy_Access_To\")
if not objfso.folderexists(Depo) then
objFSO.CreateFolder(Depo)
end if
```

These no longer work when using Folder Redirection. I'm hoping there is a work around for this because a lot of my existing scripts depend on this variable remaining valid. I've found that .NET is able to pull the redirected folder with:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

I haven't had much luck find an equivalent for VBS though.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think SpecialFolders is what you are looking for

```
Depo=oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Test"
```

It will return the location of the Desktop-folder also with Redirected Folders.

Comment: Thank you so much, would you happen to know any good reference sites that would have this kind of documentation?  This should have been a really easy thing to look up but I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: You can find the WScript documentation on SpecialFolders here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156616.aspx